# "She stole to keep her boyfriend in luxury"

Tags: meaning

Could anybody please tell me the exact meaning of it? Is it used in everyday English? And could we use it in written?

Comment: Note that there is a fairly major semantic difference between "boy friend" and "boyfriend" which changes the meaning of your sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s grammatical and readily understood. It means that she took things that didn’t belong to her so that she could pay for her boyfriend’s lavish lifestyle with the proceeds. If that’s what you need to say, then of course you can use it in any appropriate context.